# How to replicate MySQL data base to another Database in Same Server

Tags: mysql, replication, database-replication

I have Laravel Application with MySQL 7.3. I used windows 10 with XAMPP on my local device and I host this one in Windows Plesk Server. Now I want to replicate my database to another one on the same server. For example, I have Databases Called "A" and "B". when I do anything with "A" (like insert, update, delete) I want to make those changes automatically with "B".

Can anyone give a solution for this? I followed some articles on google. Those mention you can't replicate between the same server. What is your advice?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/65351/sync-two-mysql-databases-in-two-different-locations

Comment: You could use docker containers. Otherwise because you need to have 2 separate server instances running on the same machine. Neither of these tasks are simple since this is a rather uncommon use case. https://hub.docker.com/r/mysql/mysql-cluster/ has the docker instructions

Comment: Why? It would be better to at least have it under control of a different server process.